# Scrollspy to show where on the page I am not working with jquery code

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress

Am currently trying to add scroll spy to my WordPress one page layout with the following code but nothing happens when I scroll down the page.

The only thing that code is doing,is to remove the active class for.

```
(function( $ ){
    $("nav ul li a").addClass("marker");    
    var navLinks = $('nav ul li a'),
        navH = $('nav').height(),
        section = $('section'),
        documentEl = $(document);        
        documentEl.on('scroll', function() {            
            var currentScrollPos = documentEl.scrollTop();            
            section.each(function() {
               var self = $(this);
               if (self.offset().top < (currentScrollPos + navH ) && (currentScrollPos + navH) < (self.offset().top + self.outerHeight())) {
                   var targetClass = '.' +self.attr('class') + 'marker';
                   navLinks.removeClass('active');
                   $(targetClass).addClass('active');
               }                
            });            
        });
})(jQuery);
```

I simply added a dark background to active class in order to see he menu item changing color when I scroll down each section.

```
.active{
    background-color:#000;
}
```

How can I apply the scroll spy properly?

Comment: Are your site available via www?

Comment: @Kison.Not yet at the moment

Comment: Did you put your js in header?

Comment: No. At it's a WordPress site, my js is enqueued in m functions.php

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap your js in dom ready statement

```
jQuery(function(){
    $("nav ul li a").addClass("marker");    
    var navLinks = $('nav ul li a'),
        navH = $('nav').height(),
        section = $('section'),
        documentEl = $(document);        
        documentEl.on('scroll', function() {            
            var currentScrollPos = documentEl.scrollTop();            
            section.each(function() {
               var self = $(this);
               if (self.offset().top < (currentScrollPos + navH ) && (currentScrollPos + navH) < (self.offset().top + self.outerHeight())) {
                   var targetClass = '.' +self.attr('class') + 'marker';
                   navLinks.removeClass('active');
                   $(targetClass).addClass('active');
               }                
            });            
        });
});
```

Comment: The only thing It changed is the addition of the class active. Previously the class active was being removed after I started scolling down and now it changed so the home item is always active. thanks for it.
But the main problem remains. Cannot make each menu item get highlighted according to its section.

Comment: So, i guess that you have problem in your logic, try to use console.log in you cycle and watch what happend when you scroll your page

Comment: It will be great if you simulate page on jsfiddle, then i will see all code that related to this problem and problem will be fixed faster